# EXTNAME Array declaration

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a problem pretty similiar to the below:

I need to store the data of studentIDs along with 10 of their favourite foods in an RPG variable.
The best option would be obviously a data structure array.

But as a standard, all DS definitions must reference an external DS (File structure) which obviously can be done using EXTNAME and EXTFLD.

So, the file structure (STUDREF) I create would look like this:

```
STUDENTID INTEGER
FOOD      CHAR(10)
```

And the DS would look like this:

```
dcl-ds StudentData EXTNAME('STUDREF') qualified;
    StudentID      EXTFLD('STUDENTID');
    FavoriteFoods  LIKE(StudentData.FOOD) DIM(10); --> Note that I cant use EXTFLD here as this is an array.
end-ds;
```

Considering that the standard mandates to have all Datastructures be defined externally, this should work.

But the problem is, if I do an EVAL StudentData in Debug, I see the array elements like this:

```
StudentData(1).StudentID = 123
StudentData(1).FOOD = ' '                  ----> This is the problem!!
StudentData(1).FavoriteFoods(1) = 'Burger'
StudentData(1).FavoriteFoods(2) = 'PIZZA'
StudentData(1).FavoriteFoods(3) = 'CANDY'
.
.
.
StudentData(1).FavoriteFoods(10) = 'ICE CREAM'
```

The FOOD variable obviously "inherited" from the STUDREF structure is really unwanted for me.

Is there any simple way to get rid of this but using EXTNAME at the same time?

Now coming to the actual situation I am facing in my production code, similiar to above, I need to add a new array (similiar to FavoriteFoods above) to an existing DS.
The DS is used as a one of the parms (in dcl-pi) of an RPG API program.

So the coding standard mandates that the DCL-PI Data structures should be defined externally.

So, What I did was to add a new field to the Structure Table (FOOD variable in STUDREF in example above) and declared the new variable in the DS
similiar to FavoriteFoods  `LIKE(StudentData.FOOD) DIM(10).`

But as I noted, there was the variable "FOOD" also added to each instance of the DS array which I dont want.

Any good solutions to achieve this or any other general comments ?

Answer (score 2):

Using EXTNAME will bring in all the fields from the file.  I don't think there's a way to select which ones you want unless it's just key fields.

So, to make your DS the way you want, first, define an external DS based on the PF to get the fields available.  It could be qualified if you want.  I didn't in this example.

```
dcl-ds STUDREFDS EXTNAME('STUDREF'); 
End-ds;
```

All this does is bring in the field references from the file to be used when defining other variables.

Then create your DS using LIKE from the definitions:

```
dcl-ds StudentData qualified;
    StudentID      LIKE(STUDENTID);
    FavoriteFoods  LIKE(FOOD) DIM(10);
end-ds;
```

Now you will just have StudentData.StudentID and StudentData.FavoriteFoods (array).

Comment: When dealing with this kind of thing, I often find it helpful to add Template to the ExtName data structure declaration as well.  That prevents you from accidentally using the actual record field names when you mean to use the names in StudentData in this case.

Comment: @Player1st , Could you please elaborate?

Comment: `dcl-ds STUDREFDS EXTNAME('STUDREF') Template; 
End-ds;`

This will cause compile errors if you try and use the fields from STUDREF directly rather than the fields defined in the StudentData data structure.

Answer (score 1):

@bvstone's suggestion is a good one. It lets you follow the rule about using external definitions for your subfields, while still allowing you to define the data structure the way you want.

@Theju112, there's an IBM Idea related to this: "Update RPG compiler to define variables using a means like REFFLD() in DDS"

If that feature was available, you wouldn't need the TEMPLATE data structures. You could just define the StudentData DS directly.

You can vote for the Idea here: https://ibm-power-systems.ideas.ibm.com/ideas/IBMI-I-2448

Answer (score 0):

I assume the reason for the rule that all DS's must be externally defined is to make sure that you don't hand code the same DS repeatedly.

That's not necessarily a bad idea. However, limiting yourself to EXTNAME is in my mind a bad idea.

Instead, consider defining your DS in a /COPY member.  Possibly in the same /COPY member with the prototypes for any procedures that work with such a DS.

EXTNAME is something left over from RPG III; when DS were pretty simple and EXTNAME was the only option.  RPG IV offers much more powerful data structures that EXTNAME just can't support.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your valuable answers!
I have been really thinking hard about this and think I have found a solution but please do point out if you see issues with this.

So, the best way technically is to declare a template DS using EXTNAME and then declare the actual DS subfields using LIKE instead of EXTFLD.

The DS in this case as I mentioned, is to be used as the return parameter which holds the data to be returned by the API.

And to me, it feels that the structure it refers to, should logically match the data being returned.

Meaning, though I could declare FOOD in the external file and create an array of 10 favourite food items using `FavoriteFoods like(StudRef.Food) DIM(10)` , to me it seems that the External file structure does not really match the output from the API(the DS that is). Because, there are 10 "food" items being returned whereas somebody looking at the table might think the API returns 1 food item.

So what I think is that the file field should be defined as a character field of length 200, which would allow the DS to be declared like the below:

```
dcl-ds StudentData qualified;
    StudentID      EXTNAME('STUDENTID');
    FavoriteFoods  EXTNAME('FOOD') DIM(10);
end-ds;
```

So, somebody looking at the table structure would see that the food field has a length of 200 and in program, it has 10 dimensions each of length 20. Thus logically matching the actual API output/return value.

Please share your feedback about this!

Comment: If the only purpose for the file is to be able to use EXTNAME, then I think you should reconsider your standards as @Charles suggested. Defining a TEMPLATE data structure in a /copy file can serve the purpose of having only one place where the structure is defined. And it has the added benefit that you can define the data structure in the most convenient way for your API.

Comment: I think that defining the FOODS field in the file with length 200 somewhat violates the spirit of the rule about defining data structures with EXTNAME. Anyone using your API should be defining their data structure with the DIM keyword the same as your program, so they would have to get the definition from some /copy file anyway.

Comment: If I was forced to define this data structure in a file, I would define 10 fields FOOD01, FOOD02, FOOD03 ... FOOD10, and in my RPG program I would define an array over the FOOD01-FOOD10.

Comment: @BarbaraMorris, about defining 10 fields in the file and declaring an array over it, how to do that?

Comment: there's an example on this page. Look for "Defining an array over several repeated fields in an externally-described data structure" https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzasd/dkwsamepos.htm